# Showing $T:K^n \to K^{n-1}$ is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

[image]

Hi everyone, I'm a bit stuck on this question. Could anyone share some ideas?

Note: $K$ is the field

I believe from the definition of the $ker(T)$ we can tell $n = 3$, but I am unsure as to how this will help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the dimension equality you have that. $\dim \mathrm{Im T} = \dim \mathrm{K}^n - \dim \ker T$ Since the Kernel is one dimensional you get that $\dim \mathrm{Im T} = n -1$ and therefore it is surjective.

Comment: This was exactly my answer. I'm a slow typer. +1.

Comment: This identity is often called the *Rank-Nullity Theorem*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is appreciated! I should've thought to use R-N theorem.. but how come we are saying dim(K^n) = (n+1)? is it not n?

Comment: Ah you're right. I had the dimension mixed up in my head. I was thinking about a map from $K^{n+1}$ to $K^n$.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Sorry to ask again, but how does $Rank(T) = (n-1)$ imply it is surjective?

Comment: Well since the dimension of $K^{n-1}$ is $n-1$ you get that the image of $T$ is a linear subspace of dimension $n-1$ but there is only one linear subspace of $K^{n-1}$ of dimension $n-1$ namely $K^{n-1}$.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? For instance, if our field was K =$\mathbb{C}^2$, would $\mathbb{R}^2$ not also be a linear subspace of K with a dimension equal to that of the field?

Comment: You need to keep track of "what" dimension your looking at. $\mathbb{C}$ has the $\mathbb{R}$-vectorspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but $\mathbb{R}$ has no $\mathbb{C}$-vectorspace structure (at least not any one extending the real vectorspace structure). Dimension are always taken over a specific field. For example $\mathbb{R}$ has $\dim_{\mathbb{R}} 1$ but $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\infty$.